# How to make particle based fluid simulator like Algodoo?

Tags: physics-engine, fluid-dynamics

I need to create swim mechanism which is interaction between object actuator and water.
I've play Algodoo and I can make simple swiming mechine. Which priciple to achieve this?
As far as I know it just round particle bouncing and update its momentum with viscositiy.
I just want what I need to know.

Comment: "particle bounding and updating its momentum with viscosity" sounds like a great starting point. How have you tried implementing this based on your research thus far?

Comment: @DMGregory. Particle it’s self look fine but. My problem is how it interacts with body and actuators.  I’m completely no idea.